# what is the Balance factor in AVL tree

Tags: avl-tree, presentation, tree-balancing

I'm making presentation for AVL tree, can't understand what is the balance factor.
please give me the link or any thing that I can understand graphically how height of an AVL tree's height effect

Comment: difference between the height of the left sub tree and right sub tree is balance factor when the factor is 1,0, or -1 the tree is balanced otherwise unbalanced (As far as my memory is concerned)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly.

> Difference between the height of the left sub tree and right sub tree is the balance factor of an AVL tree.when the factor is 1,0, or -1 the tree is balanced otherwise unbalanced .

Play with [AVL tree applet](http://www.site.uottawa.ca/~stan/csi2514/applets/avl/BT.html) to get some intuition on this

See this link for [Balance Factor](http://www.cs.duke.edu/courses/summer10/cps130/files/L6-AVLTrees.pdf%E2%80%8E)